# ImportError from dynamically imported module trying to load module in same directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

Consider the following setup:

```
[~/test]$ tree .
.
├── main.py
└── pkg
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    ├── c.py
    └── __init__.py

1 directory, 5 files
[~/test]$ cat main.py 
from pkg import a

[~/test]$ cat pkg/a.py 
print "Importing b using import statement"
import b

print "\nImporting b dynamically"
import imp
import os
b = imp.load_source('b', os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/b.py')

[~/test]$ cat pkg/b.py 
import c

[~/test]$ cat pkg/c.py 
print 'Hello from c.py'
```

The behavior that I would expect here is that the `import c` line from b.py would work fine even when b.py is imported dynamically, so that this code would give the following :

```
[~/test]$ python main.py
Importing b using import statement
Hello from c.py

Importing b dynamically
Hello from c.py
```

However instead I get the following:

```
[~/test]$ python main.py
Importing b using import statement
Hello from c.py

Importing b dynamically
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg import a
  File "/home/f.j/test/pkg/a.py", line 8, in <module>
    b = imp.load_source('b', os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/b.py')
  File "/home/f.j/test/pkg/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import c
ImportError: No module named c
```

So the questions here:

- Why is the behavior different when dynamically importing the module?
- Are there any changes I can make **in a.py only** so that the `import c` statement from b.py works correctly even when b.py is imported dynamically?

Note that I can get this to work by changing the import statement in b.py to `from pkg import c`, but I don't want to have to do this.  The expectation here is that a module should always be able to import other modules contained within the same directly without specifying the full package location or manipulating `sys.path`.

I have already tried the following in a.py:

```
# this gives the same behavior as imp.load_source
b = imp.load_module('b', *imp.find_module('b', [os.path.dirname(__file__)]))

# with this I get 'ImportError: No module named b'
b = __import__('b')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dynamically importing a *top level module* `b`, which is a different module from `pkg/b`.

Because `sys.path` doesn't include `/home/f.j/test/pkg`, `c` is not found from `b`, which is trying to import a top-level module `c` at that moment. The `pkg.b` module, on the other hand tries to find first a top-level module `c`, then a local `pkg.c`.

Instead, import `pkg.b`:

```
b = imp.load_source('pkg.b', os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/b.py')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is that b.py doesn't understand it is part of 'pkg' and that the relative path is used for a generic import.

You can make it import c by modifying **b.py** as:

```
from pkg import c
```

More correctly however, you can tell **b.py** that it is part of **pkg** by modifying **b.py** to say:

```
__package__ = 'pkg'
import c
```

I would be very interested in understanding **why** you need to do this in the first place as it seems kind of scary.

Comment: It probably is a bad idea, but I was investigating the feasibility of being able to drop a Python module into a specific directory and having the application detect and use pieces from that module.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I can see why you would want to do this, for a plugin system this is a fairly common idiom, another way to handle it would be to just insure that the module names are consistent and use inotify or kevents to load newly detected files on the fly - watch for. .py suffixed file close() events and then use __import__('filename') - which sounds pretty much like what you're doing - carry on citizen !